# Loop through an array of Perch CMS taglines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, perch

this is a rather complicated request.

So there are three elements to my problem. A JQuery [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/), a Perch CMS set of taglines that my client **must** be able to update after website release and a javascript code block.

What I want to be able to do is create a function that replaces the `<h2>` element with the appropriate tagline (i.e. second product equals item 2 in perch) when the jQuery bxslider changes the image behind it.

So here's the HTML in question

```
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="tagbox"> 
                        <h2>We provide business and personal insurance to suit your individual needs</h2>
                        <a class="read-more">Read more</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the standard script for the bxSlider

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: true, 
            auto: true,
            useCSS: false
            // onSlideAfter: /*NEED CHANGING FUNCTION HERE*/
        });
```

And I need a jQuery script that will use the array of taglines which I get using:

`<?php perch_content('Taglines');?>`

I've tried to do something like this for my function:

```
        $(".tagbox h2").html(/*NEED TO GET ARRAY INDEX HERE i.e. heading 2, 3, 4*/);
```

I've tried using the `$each()` function to loop through that comes with jQuery but with no success. Can anyone suggest anything? Really tricky concept and I could do it if my client weren't so dependent on updating content with Perch.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with another slider, see this question: [In JSSOR, how to access the current caption via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971335/in-jssor-how-to-access-the-current-caption-via-javascript)

In the same Perch template where editors enter the carousel images, you can number content (e.g. by ID) with `perch_item_zero_index` (starts at 0) or `perch_item_index` (starts at 1):

```
<li>
    <img src="/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" />
   <div id="caption-slide-<perch:content id="perch_item_zero_index" type="hidden" />"><perch:content type="text" id="caption" label="Text for the tagline" required="true"  /></div>
</li>
```

So the editors will enter these taglines in the same item as the slide image in perch.

As you write, bxslider has a callback for the end of each transition, so that's good. Note that the slider is initialised by assigning it to `var slider`, so you can access that later:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSlideAfter: function(){
    // get the text and place it somewhere else
  }
});
```

Now all you need is to know which slide you're in. See http://bxslider.com/options
If you know that, you can fetch your content at the end of each transition and place it somewhere else in the DOM:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSlideAfter: function(){
    // which slide are we in?
    var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
    // get the text from the caption that corresponds to the current slide 
    // and place it somewhere else in the dom
    $(".tagline h2").text($("#caption-slide-" + current).text());
  }
});
```

Untested, but basically, that should be it. Note that there is an issue on https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/604 saying that it might not work yet with "auto".